# Samsung CLX 3175 FN IP conflict

Tags: printing, printer

I installed a Samsung CLX 3175 FN.  When I added it to the network it was found easy enough.  But when I printed a test page the printer says IP conflict.  I tried the trouble shooter but no help there.  Any ideas how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the printer from the network, and try pinging its IP address. Does another computer respond? If so, there's an IP conflict.

With network printers, it's best to assign it an IP address, outside of your DHCP range. For example, most Linksys routers issue addresses from `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.1.200`. If you assign it an address such as `192.168.1.250`, it should be out of the range, and not cause conflicts.

Before picking an address, try pinging that address. You want an address that is not being used at the time, and that won't be assigned later on.